# How do you get initial user base on social networking website?

Tags: users, social-media

Ok, so here's the problem. Getting users to the website is not the problem. Getting users to a website that they want to visit with other users is the problem.

I am developing a dating website and expected to launch soon. But, with EVERY dating website, you can expect, when you register, to search for other users and bam... other users found.

However, when you first launch, you probably only have a handful of users (the people you work with, if any). How can I get users if I don't already have users? Since that's the ENTIRE point of this type of website. Some websites I know have bots to auto create profiles, but I don't want to do that. I want only real users, real profiles.

Comment: Unfortunately this is too [opinion-based and open-ended](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for this site.

Comment: @dan I don't know when StackExchange will start allowing these questions, they are important questions though and I really want to know some answers or opinions

Comment: Likely never - opinions don't fit the format of a technical Q & A site with voting & accepting, but forums do. You might try posting your question on some of those instead to get opinions.